# Hibernate Exception - Transient Object Exception

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have been going through the web about this exception. I found many articles and tried to fix it but unfortunatley after all the time I spent I am still getting the same error.

hbm.xml file..

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="AbstractLoadKey" table="loadkey" abstract="true">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator">
                <param name="sequence_name">hibernate_sequence</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <discriminator type="string" length="1" column="subclass" not-null="true"/>
        <version name="version" type="long" column="version"/>
        <property name="insertTime" type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime" column="INSERTTIME"/>
        <property name="updateTime" type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime" column="UPDATETIME"/>
        <component name="origin" class="SortPlan">
            <property name="country" type="string" length="2" column="orig_country" not-null="true" />
            <property name="slic" type="string" length="5" column="orig_slic" not-null="true" />
            <property name="portCode" type="string" length="5" column="orig_portcode" not-null="true" />
            <many-to-one
                name="code"
                class="SortCode"
                column="orig_sort_id"
                foreign-key="domloadplan_origsort_fk"
                index="domloadplan_origsort_fk"
                not-null="true"
            />
```

I want to save the many-to-one property in the main table but not in the `SortCode` (Many-to-one related table)

calling this method in controller:

```
dkey = domLoadKeyDao.read(dkey);

    @Transactional
    public DomLoadKey read(DomLoadKey domLoadKey) {
        Session s = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Criteria c = s.createCriteria(getEntityClass());
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("origin.country", domLoadKey.getOrigin().getCountry()));
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("origin.slic", domLoadKey.getOrigin().getSlic()));
        .
        .
        .
        DomLoadKey result = (DomLoadKey) c.uniqueResult();
        if(result == null)
        return domLoadKey;
        return result;
}
```

When I go in to see where it is failing, at this particular snippet it fails..instead of going to `success = true` it comes out of it..

this snippet is from

```
sessionImpl.class

boolean success = false;
        try {
            for( int i=0; i<size; i++ ) {
                final List currentResults = loaders[i].list(this);
                currentResults.addAll(results);
                results = currentResults;
            }
            success = true;
        }
        finally {
            dontFlushFromFind--;
            afterOperation(success);
        }
```

And this is the line where it fails..

```
final List currentResults = loaders[i].list(this);
```

and this line further calls this method and fails,

```
public List list(SessionImplementor session) 
    throws HibernateException {
        return list( session, translator.getQueryParameters(), querySpaces, resultTypes );

    }
```

I have all my Dao's `autowired` in my controller like,

```
@Autowired
private SortCodeDao sortCodeDao;
```

Using spring MVC, Hibernate in my application. using criteriaImpl, before returning when it comes here

```
DomLoadKey result = (DomLoadKey) c.uniqueResult();
```

it is giving the exception. I have similar method to

```
IntlLoadKey
```

which is working. But when it comes to Dom its failing..

Following is my stacktrace..

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ca.ups.tle.sortCode.SortCode
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1873)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:369)
    at ca.ups.tle.loadKey.DomLoadKeyHbmDao.read(DomLoadKeyHbmDao.java:74)
    at ca.ups.tle.loadKey.DomLoadKeyHbmDao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3036def2.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at ca.ups.tle.loadKey.DomLoadKeyHbmDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$71e33677_2.read(<generated>)
    at ca.ups.tle.web.controller.assignLoads.NISLoadEntryController.usePositionInformationNis(NISLoadEntryController.java:1010)
    at ca.ups.tle.web.controller.assignLoads.NISLoadEntryController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c0ff7011.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at ca.ups.tle.web.controller.assignLoads.NISLoadEntryController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$64e555c_2.usePositionInformationNis(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.ActionTransitionCriteria.test(ActionTransitionCriteria.java:82)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionCriteriaChain.test(TransitionCriteriaChain.java:71)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.canExecute(Transition.java:195)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:211)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: try to specify your question a bit more detailed. nobody knows anything about `DomLoadKey` or `c.uniqueResult();` etc.

Comment: @sics updated a little more..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the DomLoadKey you are trying to load here was previously attached to a session, made dirty and never persisted. When that session was closed it entity got dettached. Now you're trying to fetch the same entity which hibernate knows is in a dirty state, hence the exception. It does not necessarily need to be the DomLoadKey that is dirty, it could also be a referenced entity that was not persisted.

You either need to make sure all changes are persisted before a session gets closed or reattach the entity to the new session. It depends on your use case.

Comment: i tried checking for it..`session.isDirty()` which gives me false!